# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint using Ajax in ASP.net MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I got the following error.
using MVC5, EF6, and web api.

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Attendances_dbo.Gigs_GigId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-GigHub-20170521125426", table "dbo.Gigs", column 'Id'.

```
{System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Attendances_dbo.Gigs_GigId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-GigHub-20170521125426", table "dbo.Gigs", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.    <Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at GigHub.Controllers.AttendancesController.Attend(Int32 gigId) in D:\Visual studio 2017 online projects\GigHub\GigHub\Controllers\AttendancesController.cs:line 39}
```

i have following Attendance model class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace GigHub.Models
{
    public class Attendance
    {
        public Gig Gig { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Attendee { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int GigId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public string AttendeeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Event Bound to following button
[image]

Script of button event handling is following

```
@section scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".js-toggle-attendance").click(function(e) {
                var button = $(e.target);
                $.post("/api/Attendances/", button.attr("data-gig-id").valueOf())
                    .done(function() {
                        button.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Going");
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        alert('Something Failed');
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

My post method is like as following,
but i don't understand why gigiId parameter has 0 value it should be 4 instead
[image]

Comment: Have you examined your request (in your browser's network tab) to see if the gigId value is in the request body correctly and with the right name? I supect you need to name it when sending in the $.post command

Comment: @ADyson this is my Network Tab 
'Request URL:http://localhost:41230/api/Attendances
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:41230
Referer:http://localhost:41230/Home/Index
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
4:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need this to get the value of attribute data-gig-id.

```
button.attr("data-gig-id")
```

Remove valueOf() and also add parameter name when ajax post may work.

```
$.post("/api/Attendances", { "gigId": button.attr("data-gig-id") })
                .done(function() {
                    button.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Going");
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert('Something Failed');
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Finally found solution. I have used DTO object instead of parameter `[FromBody] int gigId` and it resolved. And yes i had removed `.valueOf()` but it didn't work out. 

Still don't understand why it works with DTO and not with primitive type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding property name `gigId`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".js-toggle-attendance").click(function(e) {
                var button = $(e.target);
                $.post("/api/Attendances/", { "gigId": button.attr("data-gig-id") })
                    .done(function() {
                        button.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Going");
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        alert('Something Failed');
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: this is what i got in Network tab after changing 

Request URL:http://localhost:41230/api/Attendances
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:41230
Referer:http://localhost:41230/Home/Index
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
gigId:4

Comment: I knew, don't use **valueOf()**

Comment: Thanks for the help. Finally found solution. I have used DTO object instead of parameter `[FromBody] int gigId` and it resolved. And yes i had removed `.valueOf()` but it didn't work out. 

Still don't understand why it works with DTO and not with primitive type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Finally found solution. I have used DTO object instead of parameter `[FromBody] int gigId` and it resolved. And yes i had removed `.valueOf()` but it didn't work out.

Still don't understand why it works with DTO and not with primitive type parameter.